# MoveIt's motion planning model does not match RobotModel's

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, ros-melodic, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I have a robot arm attached to a linear actuator in Gazebo. MoveIt has been set up for the arm without issues.

I proceeded to combine the URDF of the arm and the linear actuator. I'm able to view the combined model in RVIZ.

When I move the linear actuator, RobotModel updates accordingly. However, MotionPlanning does not, i.e. it thinks the actuator has not moved. Moving the arm still works, and they update the arm for both models. So I am seeing two representations in RVIZ, which I'm guessing should not be the right behaviour...

Any pointers on how to debug this would really be appreciated, as I have been struggling with this for some time! Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351493/moveit%27s-motion-planning-model-does-not-match-robotmodel%27s/) by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve it! My mistake was in the URDF file of the linear actuator, where the prismatic joint's axis was specified wrongly as

`axis xyz="0.0 0.0 0.01"`

instead of

`axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"`

Therefore, MoveIt was scaling down the joint values by a factor of 100.
For future reference, this matches the specifications in [the URDF wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint%22), which states:

> xyz (required): Represents the components of a vector. The vector should be **normalized**.

---

Originally posted by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) with karma: 87 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0